# Is this a safe way to implement error-handling?

Tags: c++, pointers, if-statement, variable-assignment

Today I saw a code example where error handling is done by checking if assignment to a pointer worked. I guess if it didn't, it would return false...

My question is, **will it always work**? Wouldn't it be better to just check if it's a `nullptr`?

```
bool pop (Node *&stack, int *data){

    Node *elem;
    if (!(elem = stack)) return false;  // isn't it better to say if (!stack)?

    *data = elem->data;
    stack = elem->next;

    delete elem;
    return true;

}
```

P.S. This code is basically an implementation for `pop` function on a stack, that is implemented using linked list structure `Node`.

Comment: U know c++ has a built in stack

Comment: it is not checking assignment "worked", it is checking `stack` is not `nullptr`

Comment: @aaronman Reinvent the wheel, if you want to figure out how a wheel works.

Comment: @aaronman tell that to an interviewer who asks you to implement one ;)

Comment: @Jashaszun well he's re inventing it wrong because c++'s stack uses a deque as a backend not a linked list

Comment: @aaronman Dude this is not even my code. I'm trying to analyze it that's all.

Comment: @aaronman: `std::stack` can use any container as a backend, as long as it supports the right operations.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley there is a reason deque is the default, all I'm sayin

Comment: @aaronman indeed, however OP meant stack the datastructure, not stack the c++ collection.

Comment: @AdrianPanasiuk I know, I think I just had an averse reaction to seeing a reference to a pointer ( `Node *&stack` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `elem = stack` is also an expression and the value of this expression is the value assigned to `elem` and not whether the assignment succeeded. So indeed, `!(elem = stack)` is true iff `stack` is null, because `elem` will be assigned the value of `stack` even if it's null. It also has the side effect of assigning the value `stack` to the variable `elem`.

This is why code like `max = min = current;` is used, it means `max = (min = current);`. This, in turn, in plain english would read as: assign the value of the expression `min = current` to the variable `max`. The evaluation of `(min=current)` itself yields a side effect of assigning `current` to `min`. In effect, the whole is equivalent to `min=current; max=current;`